# Convert JSON to Mongoose Document (along with sub document object)

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to covert nested JSON into mongoose document and subdocument and kind of not able to do it. I have searched web a lot and could not find any useful.

Runkit Link: https://runkit.com/codesnooker/5a391097232f800012605983

Here is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

const FbProfileSchema = new Schema({
    fb_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    },
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
}, {
    toJSON: {
        transform: function (doc, ret) {
            var key = ret._id.toHexString();
            delete ret._id;
            ret._id = key;
        }
    }
});

const UserModel = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    },
    fbProfile: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: FbProfileSchema
    },
});

var FbProfile = mongoose.model('FbProfile', FbProfileSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserModel);

var json = "{\"fbProfile\":{\"_id\":\"5a38f1aff8920ebf2b098f40\",\"last_name\":\"My Last Name\",\"first_name\":\"My First Name\",\"fb_id\":\"temp_fb_id\",\"__v\":0},\"email\":\"temp.email@gmail.com\",\"__v\":0,\"_id\":\"5a38f1aff8920ebf2b098f41\"}";

var userJSON = JSON.parse(json);
var user = new User(userJSON);
```

And I am getting the output as follows:
[image]

But I would like to have fbProfile populated also so that I need not to hit db when using it in the project. Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If a schema has a reference property to another collection then [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) can be used to fetch and set that reference to the parent document.

```
User.findOne({
  email: 'foo@bar.com'
}).populate('fbProfile').exec().then(/* do something */);
```

Comment: With mongo query it's easy. I don't want to use that. I want to convert it from the existing JSON stored in RAM.

Comment: First, for your own edification, **JSON** is a string and not an object hence it's abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have is colloquially referred to as a **POJO** or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript **O**bject. They are different. :) Okay, by your example the only data in that object is an ID for the `fbProfile` you want to access. So unless you have that in memory already you will need to fetch it from the DB one way or the other. If you have it in memory already, then you can merge it into this object to create the same output.

Comment: I have already fbProfile data in memory. Just want to convert it into right Mongoose Document